# How to print out variable values in servlets on HTML pages?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I would like to print out my current variable value on my HTML page. I cannot seem to figure it out. On my HTML page, I want to print out the current Exchange rate.

This is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="Converter" method="get" name="frm">
Amount:
<input name="amount" type="text" />
Rate:
<input name="conversionRate" type="text" />

<input type="submit" value="Convert!" />
<br>Current Rate:
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My Java Code

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Converter
 */
@WebServlet("/Converter")
public class Converter extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Converter() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    String n2 = "1.0";

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                String n1 = request.getParameter("amount");
                String tempStr;
                tempStr = request.getParameter("conversionRate");
                if(!tempStr.isBlank()) {
                    n2 = tempStr;
                }

                if(n2.equals("tempStr")){
                     out.println((Integer.parseInt(n1) / Double.parseDouble(n2)));
                }
                else if(n2.equals(n2)){
                    out.println("test");
                    out.println((Integer.parseInt(n1) / Double.parseDouble(n2)));
                }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

How can I print out the current rate. Which in this case is n2 on my HTML page? I want it to update on each load of the website. But I cannot figure out how to print out the variable value through the HTML page.

Comment: You would either have us a view/templating technology like JSP or Thymeleaf to render the data OR expose a controller that returns the value and contact the endpoint using JavaScript. If you are just building a simple/test app, I would advise JSP/Thymeleaf or comparable technology. That being said, depending on how complex your use case is, you might be able to do all you need just with simple JavaScript (not Java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your PrintWriter instance to print the whole HTML into the response object, example:

```
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Bla</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>");
        out.println("Your current rate is: ");

        //Your Java code here

            String n1 = request.getParameter("amount");
            String tempStr;
            tempStr = request.getParameter("conversionRate");
            if(!tempStr.isBlank()) {
                n2 = tempStr;
            }

        out.println(n2);
        out.println("</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
```

Hope that helps.